# Creating A Login and Mapping to ALL Databases at Once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to execute the following tsql

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN UserTest WITH Password = 'hi'
GO

sp_msforeachdb @command1= "CREATE USER [UserTest] FOR LOGIN [UserTest]"
```

Getting the following error repeatedly (for each DB):

```
Msg 15023, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
User, group, or role 'UserTest' already exists in the current database.
```

Is my understanding of sp_msforeachdb incorrect? Basically I'm trying to Create 'UserTest' as a user on each database from the existing login 'UserTest' (User Mapping) without having to go write code for each database individually. Am I approaching this task the wrong way?

**Somewhat of a beginner in TSQL. Just trying to understand the language more thoroughly**

Comment: This is off topic and is more suited for dba.se

Comment: @Pondlife not sure I like the duplicate, only because the accepted answer there recommends an unsupported, undocumented and problematic hidden procedure. Would rather punt this to dba.SE than close as a dupe of that.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, that's definitely a good point and I agree with you. FYI, one 'common' scenario that will trigger the bug you mentioned is SharePoint 2010, which appends a GUID to its database names so they're no longer regular identifiers.

Comment: @Pondlife I guess nobody else pays attention to the comments before casting their close vote. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use sp_msforeachdb. It is undocumented, unsupported, and has a bug that I've pointed out many times where it can actually skip databases. I've written two alternatives:

- [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

What you should do is use one of these superior replacements, or just create the command yourself. You should also check if the user already exists instead of just throwing a potential error over the wall at SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' 
  + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.database_principals
  WHERE name = N''UserTest'')
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N''USE ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
       + ';CREATE USER UserTest FOR LOGIN UserTest;'';'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4;

PRINT @sql; -- just to debug the first 8K

-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql; 
-- uncomment the above line when you're happy with the output
```

You could also add error handling there, e.g.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' 
  + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.database_principals
  WHERE name = N''UserTest'')
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N''USE ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
    + ';CREATE USER UserTest FOR LOGIN UserTest;'';
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ''Did not work for ' + name + ';''
  END CATCH
END'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4;

PRINT @sql;

-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `?` value is used as a placeholder for the database name, so your example would be:

```
sp_msforeachdb @command1= 'USE [?]; CREATE USER [UserTest] FOR LOGIN [UserTest];'
```

Please be aware of pitfalls documented [here](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior) when working with with the undocumented stored procedure.